# Cover a body background by another image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cover up a html body background image by another image. I used z-index but can't get it working. Am I missing something or just can't understand what I'm doing.

See sample code below:

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1176-907-10.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#main-content {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-633-1.jpg');
    z-index: 10;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    /*height: 700px;*/
    height: 100vh;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    /*margin-top: 20%;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
</div>
```

> Additionaly, inside the `main-content` are divs with `100vh` and
>   `background opacity`

Main content images should be on top of everything including the `content` div with background opacity.

Comment: You have not given the div any width or height, try adding them

Comment: @Akshay, it works man! but can't get it working on my actual page. It's weird

Comment: How did you set the width and height ? like `100%` or in `px` ?

Comment: @Akshay, in percent. yes 100% width and height. I tested it using my sample and it works. maybe it's because of other divs using vh?

Comment: If you are giving `100%` height to a div, i believe that all its parents should also have `100%` height

Comment: Yes I guess it's working since the parent body has 100% height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129628/discussion-between-claudios-and-akshay).

Answer (score 1):

Use `100%` width and height on `#main-content`, like:

```
#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1176-907-10.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#main-content {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
    z-index: 10;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah it's working but can't get it working on my actual page. RIP to me

Comment: @claudios Maybe you are missing something, maybe I can help you if you can show me your actual code.

Comment: Inside the `main-content` are divs with height equal to `100vh`. Would that affect?

Comment: @claudios Can't guess without seeing the actual, if possible can you please show me the code anywhere online?

Comment: I'll try to recreate the snippet.

Comment: I added contents on my snippet. I think the opacity white background is covering the image with z-index

Comment: @claudios Yes, you are right, the opacity of `.content` inside `#main-content` is affecting the background image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129633/discussion-between-claudios-and-saurav-rastogi).

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you define a height for the div with CSS. Or insert content so it will expand vertically.

A background image makes sense for an element that contains more content, otherwise you can insert the image with <img>

Comment: Yeah, But not working in my end. Please see the new snippet

Answer (score 1):

You mean something as below, if so then set `#main-content` `height:auto` and it works fine, if you set `height:100%` then it takes that as `100vh`, which on scroll hides image placed at top, so try as below.

So now `#main-content` `height:auto` calculates and takes height assigned to child elements present inside it and the background image which is assigned to this div `#main-content` can be seen only till height of 100vh, after that the default image that is assigned to body get visible.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1176-907-10.jpg');
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;   
}

#main-content {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
    
.content {
    height: 100vh;
    background:rgba(220,60,60,0.6);
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="main-content">
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
  <div class="content">something in here..</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working. the `main-content` should be not covered with the background opacity. I tried but no joy.

Comment: @claudios it is covered change background-color and assign color to font you will find difference, as placeholder image and assigned background-color are of same shade so it difficult to identify.

Comment: My goal is to make the `main-content` top of everything. I think fonts are not the issue in here.

Comment: @claudios check my updated solution, body image is at bottom then #main-content image top of that,but now content that are present inside #main-content obviously will come at top of #main-content as they are child elements present inside #main......

Comment: The background with opacity should be at the back of the main content

Comment: @claudios then you should declare that on body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129671/discussion-between-frnt-and-claudios).